# transferring from QT4 to QT5 results in compilation error; c2666

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

My project worked well on `qt4` and now I want to run it on `qt5`.

I've fixed most of the differences and still i am getting the error: `c2666: QByteArray::operater == ': 11 overloads have similar conversions.`

How can I fix it?

the code:

h file:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <QObject>

class a
{
public:
    explicit a();
    QByteArray arr;
    int validate();
signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // A_H
```

on cpp file:

```
#include "a.h"

int a::validate()
{
    a* p = new a();
    if(p->arr == NULL)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

the error come on this line:  "if(p->arr == NULL)"

Comment: Show us the code that raises the error

Comment: the error should be accompanied with file and line, show the relevant code around that

Comment: sorry. i'v fixed my question. please answer it now!

Comment: you try to compare a `QByteArray` with `(void*)0` ... check your `a* p` variable to be not null and if needed the size of `p->arr`

Answer (score 0):

> if(p->arr == NULL)

That is not OK. `arr` is not a pointer in this context, nor an integer, so it cannot be `NULL`.

You could either use [the isNull() method from QByteArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html#isNull)

```
if (p->arr.isNull())
```

or write

```
if (p)
```

depending on your scenario whether you wish to check againt proper construction or memory allocation failure.

Also, you are trying to use slots in a class that does not have the Q_OBJECT macro, nor does the class inherit QObject. That is also wrong. Slots are not a generic C++ feature for any single C++ class. It is a Qt extension.

Furthermore, you may not wish to make the `arr` member public as it is unusual to make member variables public in a class. Usually, they are accessible by member methods.